# ffmpeg - how to see what scaling algorithm is used

Tags: linux, shell, ffmpeg

I'm upscaling a 200x200 video to 400x400 using the `-sws_flags` scaling option to set the scaling algorithm. Now, I can't tell by the console output if some algorithm was used, neither by the looks of the output video when resized. And also the video remains the same size after trying different scaling algorithms. I now can't tell if some algorithm was used or not. 
How can I found out or see in the console or even afterwards what scaling algorithm was used?

Command-line looks like this:

`ffmpeg -i old_vid_200x200.mkv -vf scale=400:400 -sws_flags lanczos new_vid_400x400.mkv`

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the console output as well?

Comment: You can just try the command above on some random video. Anyway, I think my attempt to resize a video smoothly failed. Quality of the result Video is way to bad to be considerable. I have tried all of the algorithms now. You can try out the algorithms with `ffplay` also.

Answer (score 3):

I've read that `-vf scale=400:400 -sws_flags lanczos` can be buggy so it is better to use `-vf scale=400:400:flags=lanczos` instead. ([source](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/26157/ffmpeg-scaler-options-not-working#comment36993_26157))

To see the scaling algorithm you can use `-loglevel verbose` and/or add `print_info` flag to the scaler (example: `-vf scale=400:400:flags=lanczos+print_info`). ([source](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).